# Angular 5 Material Autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to do an autocomplete, when I do it with only one service it works fine, but when I call more services, something strange, in the autocomplete they sell me options of a single service in the 3 services that I call.

[In this image I get options from the supplier in the product, I do not know why that happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpwI9.png)

```
<div class="example-container">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput formControlName="Id_Product" placeholder="Producto" class="form-control" id="Id_Product"  [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" required>
      <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of filteredProducts | async" [value]="option.NameProduct">
          {{ option.NameProduct }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="color-required" *ngIf="FormDetailProductCreate.get('Id_Product').touched && FormDetailProductCreate.get('Id_Product').invalid">
      Producto es requerido
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="example-container">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput formControlName="Id_TypeProduct" placeholder="Tipo de producto" class="form-control" id="Id_TypeProduct"  [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" required>
      <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of filteredTypeProducts | async" [value]="option.NameTypeProduct">
          {{ option.NameTypeProduct }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="color-required" *ngIf="FormDetailProductCreate.get('Id_TypeProduct').touched && FormDetailProductCreate.get('Id_TypeProduct').invalid">
      Tipo de producto es requerido
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="example-container">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput formControlName="Id_Provider" placeholder="Proveedor" class="form-control" id="Id_Provider" [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" required>
      <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of filteredProviders | async" [value]="option.NombreProveedor">
          {{ option.NombreProveedor }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="color-required" *ngIf="FormDetailProductCreate.get('Id_Provider').touched && FormDetailProductCreate.get('Id_Provider').invalid">
      Proveedor es requerido
    </div>
  </div>
```

Component

```
myControl = new FormControl();
filteredProviders : Observable<Provider[]>;
filteredProducts : Observable<Product[]>;
filteredTypeProducts : Observable<Typeproduct[]>;
products : Product[]; providers : Provider[]; typeproducts : Typeproduct[];


getProducts(){
this.serviceproduct.getProduct().subscribe((data)=>{
  this.products = data;
  this.filteredProducts = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(val => val ? this.filterProduct(val) : this.products.slice())
  //map(val => this.filterProduct(val))
  );
});
```

}

```
getProviders(){
this.serviceprovider.getProviders().subscribe((data)=>{
  this.providers = data;
  this.filteredProviders = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(val => val ? this.filterProviders(val) : this.providers.slice())
  );
});
```

}

```
getTypeProducts(){
this.servicetypeproduct.getTypeProduct().subscribe((data)=>{
  this.typeproducts = data;
  this.filteredTypeProducts = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(val => val ? this.filterTypeProducts(val) : this.typeproducts.slice())
  );
  console.log(this.filteredTypeProducts);
});
```

}

```
filterProduct(val): Product[] {
return this.products.filter(option => 
option.NameProduct.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
```

}

```
filterProviders(val): Provider[] {
return this.providers.filter(option => option.NombreProveedor.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
```

}

```
filterTypeProducts(val): Typeproduct[] {
return this.typeproducts.filter(option => option.NameTypeProduct.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each autocomplete control must define a unique template variable. You've used `auto` for all three controls. They should each have their own - something like:

```
<input [matAutocomplete]="auto1">
<mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete">
...

<input [matAutocomplete]="auto2">
<mat-autocomplete #auto2="matAutocomplete">
...

<input [matAutocomplete]="auto3">
<mat-autocomplete #auto3="matAutocomplete">
...
```